# I can't build a blog because of nodejs

Tags: windows

when I download a nodejs,i begin with

```
$ npm install -g hexo -cli
```

but the result is

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

how can I solve it ?

[image]

Comment: Did you even install nodejs? If yes, please edit to explain how you installed it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There's no npm package for MSYS2/MINGW available.

You have to install `mingw-w64-x86_64-nodejs` instead which comes with `npm`,
but is probably enough for you by itself.

For 64-bit :

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-nodejs
```

For 32-bit :

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-nodejs
```

After installation, verify in Terminal:

```
$ node -v
v6.11.0    (or whatever is the latest)
```

Remark: If you are on Windows 10, you would get a better Linux experience than in
MSYS2/MINGW by installing Ubuntu (or other) from the Microsoft Store.